# How can I bind to a parent UIElement within an ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, itemtemplate, uielement

I'm trying to bind to a property of MainWindow, but from a `ContextMenu` within a `DataTemplate`. How can I achieve this?

- I can't use `ElementName`, as the contextMenu isn't part of the visual tree
- I can't use `PlacementTarget`, as this will give the `UIElement` produced by the `DataTemplate`

  ```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication24.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Border Padding="5" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                  <Border.ContextMenu>
                      <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding <I want to bind to a property of MainWindow here>}"/>
                  </Border.ContextMenu>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
              </Border>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the window object in `Tag` of your `Border` and then can access it using `PlacementTarget.Tag`

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Border Padding="5" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red"
           Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                        AncestorType=Window}}">
       <Border.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.PropertyName,
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
       </Border.ContextMenu>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I used is a simple `custom control wrapper` e.g. `MyContextMenu`
...with just one line of code, something like...

```
public class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    public override void EndInit()
    {
        base.EndInit();
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, NameScope.GetNameScope(App.Current.MainWindow));
    }
}
```

...and use that instead of `ContextMenu`.

That always 'scopes' to the `MainWindow` which may not always be optimal - but you can use `ElementName` etc.

2) The other option is using `NameScope.NameScope="{StaticResource myNameScope}"`
`NameScope.NameScope` seems like an optimal solution - however, you cannot bind from it (and it binds 'too late').
But you can use `{StaticResource ...}` - and you make a class which wraps around MainWindow's scope.
Similar, but I found the above 'less disruptive' (you can pretty much write the code you'd normally write).

---

For more details take a look at this answers (and for more ideas)...

[ElementName Binding from MenuItem in ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu)
[How to access a control from a ContextMenu menuitem via the visual tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333028/how-to-access-a-control-from-a-contextmenu-menuitem-via-the-visual-tree)